# Android Material design multi-line edittext gravity

Tags: android, material-design

I cannot find anything in the guides about material design about what the vertical alignment of the text inside a multi-line edittext should be? For pre-material design it felt natural to have the text gravity set to top to start to write from the top and then down to the bottom. But with material design it looks strange because there is no clear box around the text, just the thin line at the bottom.